# Odoo API with Ripcord library: how to post language parameter

Tags: php, api, odoo-10

I'm working on connecting Magento with Odoo.  I run this call:

```
$records = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $pass, 'product.product', 'read', array(array(2))
                        , array('fields' => array(
                        'id',
                        'active',
                        'categ_id',
                        'display_name',
                        'description',
                        'image',
                        '__last_update',
                        'list_price',
                        'qty_available',
                        'taxes_id',
                        'write_date',
                        'promotion_note',
                        'publish_website'
                    ),

                        )
                );
```

But how does the language parameter fit in? For the display_name and description I want the nl_BE translation. I was thinking of fitting

```
array("lang"=>"nl_BE")
```

in as argument but I get a

```
TypeError: execute_kw() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)
```

error... .  Anyone who has dealt with the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution,

```
$records = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $pass, 'product.product', 'read', array(array(2))
                        , array('fields' => array(
                        'id',
                        'active',
                        'categ_id',
                        'display_name',
                        'description',
                        'image',
                        '__last_update',
                        'list_price',
                        'qty_available',
                        'taxes_id',
                        'write_date',
                        'promotion_note',
                        'publish_website'
                    ),  "context" => array("lang" => "nl_BE")
                        )
                );
```

Hope this helps somebody